# Update SPARQL using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, sparql

Hi I am trying to create an `UPDATE` query and send it via ajax. I am continuously getting an error and the update is not done. Any idea why? When I try the `UPDATE` query on Apache Fuseki it works well.

```
function createNewItem(deed, itemNo, desc){
var itemValue =document.getElementById("search").value;
myQuery= ["PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>",
"PREFIX locah: <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/>",
"prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>",
"INSERT DATA",
"{",
"<http://natarchives.com.mt/deed/"+deed+"> locah:associatedWith <http://natarchives.com.mt/item/#item"+itemNo+">.",
"<http://natarchives.com.mt/item/#item"+itemNo+"> dcterms:description \""+desc+"\".",
"<http://natarchives.com.mt/item/#item"+itemNo+"> locah:item \""+itemValue+"\".",
"<http://natarchives.com.mt/item/#item"+itemNo+"> dcterms:identifier \""+itemNo+"\"^^xsd:integer.}"].join(" ");
window.alert(myQuery);
console.log('myQuery: '+myQuery);

$.ajax({
dataType: "jsonp",
url: myEndPointUpdate,
data: {"query": myQuery,
"output": "json"},
success: ready,
error: myError
});
console.log('After .ajax');
}
```

Comment: for Update request, you must use `update` instead of `query` as param name.

Comment: Note -- This is specific to Fuseki. Virtuoso (among others) will accept a SPARQL query using the `UPDATE` verb as a `query` param (though it must be submitted to an `UPDATE`-enabled endpoint by an `UPDATE`-permitted user).

Comment: @TallTed Well, isn't that what I said? Use `update` as param name instead of `query`.  This clearly also holds for Fuseki given the fact that this is mandatory by [SPARQL protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#update-operation) : *"Client requests for this operation **must** include exactly one SPARQL update request string (parameter name: `update`)"* - or do you mean, with Virtuoso you don't have to do this and can just append `&update` to the request?

Comment: Do you mean that this line : data: {"query": myQuery, should be data: {"update": myQuery}...I changed my endpoint to update

Comment: @AKSW - I mean, SPARQL Protocol is unnecessarily restrictive on this, and is not necessarily in use for HTTP requests (and there is no way to declare "I'm using SPARQL Protocol" on such HTTP operations). SPARQL `UPDATE` operations against Virtuoso may be performed via `GET` using `&query=` and omitting `&update=`.

Comment: @Martha - Yes, you need to change `data: {"query": myQuery,` to `data: {"update": myQuery,`.